# Events in touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have bind an mousemove and mousedown event to a div element, as below. In firefox, the event get triggers each time when i moved my finger over the div element. but in ie/chrome, the event gets triggered only for first time when i touch the div, moving the finger continuously over the div, doesnt trigger the event as in firefox.

```
this._on(this.element, 'mousemove', this.chartMouseMove);
this._on(this.element, 'mousedown', this.chartMousedown);
```

Note: Mouse event are triggered(moving mouse pointer triggers the event), only the touch is not working(moving fingers doent work).

I want the mousemove to get trigger, when i moved the finger

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should accept the answer if it was valid for you.

Answer (score 2):

For touch devices you should use `touchmove` and `touchStart`.

```
this._on(this.element, 'touchmove', this.chartMouseMove);
this._on(this.element, 'touchstart', this.chartMousedown);
```

And if you want to make it compatible with Windows Phone, then you should also add `MSPointerDown` and `MSPointerMove`:

```
this._on(this.element, 'touchmove MSPointerMove', this.chartMouseMove);
this._on(this.element, 'touchstart MSPointerDown', this.chartMousedown);
```

If you need to deal with Windows 8 touch devices, then you would need to work with `addEventHandler` instead of with `on`.

```
this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", this.chartMouseMove);
this.element.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", this.chartMousedown);
```

Also, you will need to apply the following style in your body:

```
body{
    -ms-touch-action: none;
}
```

If you don't mind using plugins for it, I would recommend you to make use of [`hand.js`](http://handjs.codeplex.com/) to make it simple :)

Comment: thanks for ur update, but that's not working. chartMousedown method gets called each time when i touch the div(ie mouseDown is working), why the mouseMove is not working

Comment: @user3326265 which touch device are you using ?

Comment: touch lap with windows 8

Comment: @user3326265 I updated my question for Windows 8 devices. Also recommended a plugin.